# How to define this dependently-typed tree structure in Coq?

Tags: coq

I’d like to define a rather simple kind of tree, but I’m not sure how to do it.

First, define a standard binary tree with natural number values, except we disallow empty trees:

```
Inductive nat_btree : Type :=
| leaf : nat -> nat_btree
| unary : nat_btree -> nat -> nat_btree
| binary : nat_btree -> nat_btree -> nat -> nat_btree.
```

Now, what I’d like to do is define a datatype we’ll call special_nat_btree which is a nat_btree with the condition that every node is either:

1. A node with value n, and no children (i.e. a leaf)
2. A node with value n+1, and a single child of value n
3. A node with value n^2, and exactly two children, each of value n

So for instance we could have the following:

```
1
|
2     2   3
 \   /    |
   4      4
    \    /
      16
       |
      17
```

But I really don’t know the right syntax or even the best approach to implementing this in Coq. My initial thinking was to demand a proof that the “root values” in the subtree(s) match what we’re trying to construct. So for instance the “unary” constructor above would become something like:

```
unary : forall (t : special_nat_btree) (n : nat),
    special_nat_btree -> nat -> (n = S (root_val t)) -> 
    special_nat_btree
```

Besides the above syntax probably being wrong already, this approach also requires defining a “root_val” function that would be in a mutual recursion with special_nat_btree. Filling out my reasoning, I get the following (this will not compile):

```
Inductive special_nat_btree : Type :=
  | leaf : nat -> special_nat_btree
  | unary : forall (t : special_nat_btree) (n : nat),
      special_nat_btree -> nat -> (n = S (root_val t)) -> 
      special_nat_btree
  | binary : forall (t_1 t_2 : special_nat_btree) (n : nat),
      special_nat_btree -> special_nat_btree -> nat ->
      (root_val t_1 = root_val t_2) ->
      (n = (root_val t_1) * (root_val t_1)) -> special_nat_btree
with
root_val (t : special_nat_btree) : nat :=
  match t with
  | leaf n => n
  | unary t' n p => n
  | binary t_1 t_2 n p_1 p_2 => n
  end.
```

And, uh, I’m pretty sure I’m way off track with this. So how should I approach this? Or, if my thinking isn't completely off, what's the correct syntax to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is it feasible to separate the implementation and the predicate? Could you have a `nat_btree` datatype and a `nat_btree_valid` predicate, or do you really want to use dependent types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this indexed type

```
(* [btree n]: tree with root value [n]. *)
Inductive btree : nat -> Type :=
| leaf : forall n, btree n
| unary : forall n, btree n -> btree (S n)
| binary : forall n, btree n -> btree n -> btree (n * n)
.
```

Then use a sigma to represent trees of indeterminate value:

```
Definition tree : Type := { n : nat & btree n }.
```

For example:

```
Example foo : tree := existT _ _
  (unary _ (binary _ (binary _ (unary _ (leaf 1))
                               (leaf 2))
                     (unary _ (leaf 3)))).
```

The `_` in the tree are actually *not* the values of the nodes as you describe, but instead the actual values (`n` in `btree n`) are computed from the contents of those fields (and so it's less confusing to just leave them off above): `unary x _` is a node with value `x+1` and its child has value `x`.